# sqlalchemy ORM create virtual column inside session and allow filter by created virtual column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have issue with SQLAlchemy query (use ORM). I'm stuck how to filter by virtual column which i created inside my query and label it **valid**. so i need to have option to filter it by virtual column

here my request:

```
  query = session.query(DocumentType.uuid,
                                  DocumentType.name_passport_element,
                                  DocumentType.period_upd_dir_id,
                                  PeriodUpdateDirectory.days_amount,
                                  Passport.uuid,
                                  Passport.user_date,
                                  Passport.date_deadline,
                                  Unit.uuid,
                                  (Passport.user_date + PeriodUpdateDirectory.days_amount > func.current_date()).label('valid'))

query = query.outerjoin(PeriodUpdateDirectory, PeriodUpdateDirectory.uuid == DocumentType.period_upd_dir_id)
            query = query.outerjoin(Passport, Passport.document_type_id == DocumentType.uuid)
            query = query.outerjoin(Unit, Unit.uuid == Passport.unit_id)
           
            query = query.filter(and_(Unit.uuid == id_))
```

I need to make possible filter also by virtual column like

`query = query.filter(and_(Unit.uuid == id_, valid = True))`

How can i achieve this?

also i tried to use sqlalchemy.cte like below:

```
found_records = query.cte()
session.query(found_records).filter(found_records.c.valid == False)
```

But it raised an Error

```
(psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn) column reference "uuid" is ambiguous
```